# declaring a typed NSMutableDictionary of blocks

Tags: objective-c

I would like to define a typed nsmutable dictionary that contains blocks.

I cannot get the right syntax.

The closes I can get is

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary<Keys*,(void(^)(NSError* _Nullable error))>* completionBlocks;
```

but it says I need a type. I tried many formats for the block but I just cannot get it

thanks :-)

Comment: I'd generally suggest you #typedef the block as a new type then use that in the declaration.   Makes things less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the brackets. Try this

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary<Keys*,void(^)(NSError* _Nullable error)>* completionBlocks;
```